# Work around for handling CPU Intensive task in aws ec2?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, backend

I have created a django application (running on aws ec2) which convert media file from one format to another format ,but during this process it consume CPU resource due to which I have to pay charges to aws.
I am trying to find a work around where my local pc (ubuntu) takes care of CPU intensive task and final result is uploaded to s3 bucket which I can share with user.

Solution :- One possible solution is that when user upload media file (html upload form)  it goes to s3 bucket and at the same time via socket connection the s3 bucket file link is send to my ubuntu where it download file, process it and upload back to s3 bucket.

Could anyone please suggest me better solution as it seems to be not efficient.

Please note :- I have decent internet connection and computer which can handle backend very well but i not in state to pay throttle charges to aws.

Comment: If you just want to avoid additional charges, you should make sure **not to use t3 instances in unlimited mode!**

Comment: @Maurice is right. It's because you are using additional CPU units. EC2 T3 instances can use extra CPU is required unless specified otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution for this is to create separate lambda function  for this task. Trigger lambda whenever someone upload files on S3. Lambda will process files and store back to S3.